# Should StringBuilder be converted to String before printing out?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Does it make a difference if printing the contents of a StringBuilder object is done directly or if the `.toString()` method is called?

In particular

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
System.out.println(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Is one style preferred over the other?

Can anyone comment on why the first way works? In Java does `System.out.println` implicitly call the `.toString()` method of an object?

Comment: One overload of it does.

Comment: The evidence: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.Object%29 And it all makes perfect sense, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

As you guessed, `PrintStream#println(Object)` indeed automatically calls the `toString()` method of an object:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Where `String.valueOf()` is:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```